# Preimage of an irreducible component of a variety.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a morphism between affine varieties. It is known that $X$ (resp. $Y$) is a finite union of irreducible components. Now, let $Y'\subset Y$ be an irreducible component.

> **Question:** (1) Is this true that $f^{-1}(Y')$ must contain an irreducible component $X'$ of $X$?
>
> (2) If (1) is not true, then may we add some additional conditions to make it true?
>
> (3) If (1) is true, then is this necessary that the restriction $f: X' \to Y'$ is dominant in the sense that $f(X')$ is dense in $Y'$?

EDIT: Maybe I should assume $f:X\to Y$ is dominant.

Answer (score 2):

Question 1. No. Consider $f$ mapping $\Bbb A^1_k$ to $\operatorname{Spec} k[x,y]/(xy)$ by inclusion into the $x$-axis. Then $f^{-1}(\{y-\mathrm{axis}\})$ is a point which does not contain an irreducible component of $\Bbb A^1_k$.

Question 2. Note that any irreducible component is closed. Since $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(Y')$ is closed. We need to find conditions that ensure there's an irreducible component $X'$ of $X$ such that that $f^{-1}(Y')\cap X'$ isn't a proper subvariety of $X'$. Anything implying this is good enough. $Y$ irreducible or $f$ locally dominant works, for instance, but isn't necessary, since projection to a point inside a positive-dimensional variety satisfies the conditions as well.

Question 3. This is false even if you assume the statement in problem 1. Consider the map which takes any variety to a point inside $\Bbb A^1$. This is a counterexample.

Comment: Thanks what if we assume the origin f is dominant

Comment: That sentence doesn't make sense (or has a typo, or something). $f$ dominant certainly implies $f$ locally dominant which is good enough, as per the post.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I mean I assume $f:X\to Y$ is dominant. I still feel confused. What do you mean by 'locally dominant'? Does it mean exactly as in (1) or (3)?

Comment: Locally dominant at a point $y$ means that there's a neighborhood $U$ of $y$ in $Y$ such that $f(X)\cap U$ is dense in $U$. This is weaker than (3).