# Is continuous preimage of a hypercomponent a union of hypercomponents?

Tags: general-topology

#### Terminology

Let $(X, \mathcal{T}_X)$ and $(Y, \mathcal{T}_Y)$ be topological spaces. A subset $U \subset X$ is [*hyperconnected*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperconnected_space), if $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$ for each $A, B \in \mathcal{T}_X|U \setminus \{\emptyset\}$. A *hypercomponent* is a subset-maximal hyperconnected subset.

#### Problem

Let $f : X \to Y$ be continuous, $V \subset Y$ be a hypercomponent of $Y$, and $U = f^{-1}(V)$.

Is $U$ a union of hypercomponents of $X$?

#### Background

If we replace hyperconnected with connected, and hypercomponent with connected component, then the result holds. However, hyperconnectedness works a bit differently, and for example hypercomponents may intersect. Here is an [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4612697/51161).

Let $(X, \mathcal{T}_X)$, $p \in X$, andh $\mathcal{T}_X = \{U \subset X : p \not\in X \} \cup \{X\}$, i.e. the excluded point topology. Then the hyperconnected subsets are

$$\{\emptyset\} \cup \{\{x\} : x \in X\} \cup \{\{x, p\} : x \in X \land x \neq p\}$$

The hypercomponents are

$$\{\{x, p\} : x \in X \land x \neq p\}$$

Comment: I feel that [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2338657/51161) provides a negative answer to this question. I just don't know what the notation there means. The hyperconnected components probably correspond to the irreducible components, and the topologies are given by Zarinski topologies.

Comment: Yes, "irreducible" is a synonym of "hyperconnected".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very generally, let $Y$ be any topological space that has two hypercomponents $X$ and $V$ which intersect, and consider the inclusion $f:X\to Y$.  Then $f^{-1}(V)=V\cap X$ is a nonempty proper subset of $X$ and thus not a union of hypercomponents since $X$ is hyperconnected.

Comment: Thanks. That is a simple counterexample. I wonder if it still fails when $f$ is surjective.

Comment: Just replace $X$ with the disjoint union $X\coprod Y$ to make this example surjective, and $f^{-1}(V)$ still won't be a union of hypercomponents.

Comment: Nice. Surely it cannot fail when $f$ is a quotient map? (You can see that I'm rooting for something like this to hold.)

Comment: The example with $X\coprod Y$ is a quotient map.

Comment: Right you are..